# How do I create a cycling function that cycles between adding and removing classes?

Tags: jquery, function

This currently works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').addClass('red').delay(50).queue(function(next){
      $(this).removeClass('red').delay(50).queue(function(next2){
        $(this).addClass('blue');
        next2();
      });
      next();
    });
```

But I'd like something more efficient. And plus, the code above becomes a headache when I start adding and removing more classes...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at jQuery's [`.toggleClass()`-function](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

**EDIT:** Try this:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('red');
    if (/* some condition */) {
        clearInterval(interval); // abort
    }
}, 50);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, although it works, it's not the solution I'm looking for. :(

Comment: Can you clearify that a bit? Do you want to add a class and remove it again after certain amounts of time?

Comment: What I really wanted was to add a class, remove it after a certain amount of time, and the cycle repeats.

Comment: Then you need to do this in a continuous timeout. I edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

use plain old `setTimeOut()` to setup intervals at every 50ms for as long as you want...

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++)setTimeout(blinkFunction, i*50);}
```